# Product attributes Inventory change scope and add extra attributes

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, inventory, scope

I want to change the scope of the product attributes of the Inventory of a product. The quantity in stock is of the GLOBAL scope. But I have different websites which have different warehouses and I'd like to have a stock per website.

I can't find the "inventory" section in the current attribute set to change the attribute's scope.

In another note, I also want to add some extra attributes to the inventory section, so I tried manually adding the "Inventory" section to the attribute set and add my created attributes there. But this just results in having 2 "inventory' tabs on the product management page.

Is there a way to access these attributes through the database to change the scope and add more attributes to the section?

I find it extremely weird that this is not possible in Magento, multistock sounds like a feature many businesses need.